# delete repeating results sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL. I'm having a slight problem - here's what I'm getting :

```
PROJECT_NO       EMPLOYEE_NO      HARDWARE       SOFTWARE  
------------------------------------------------------------
01                   1            MOUSE          SQL
01                   2            MOUSE          SQL
01                   3            MOUSE          SQL
01                   4            MOUSE          SQL
01                   1            KEYBOARD
01                   2            KEYBOARD
01                   3            KEYBOARD
01                   4            KEYBOARD
```

The employees are repeating themselves, because this project requires two types of hardware.

Here is what the tables contain:

```
Requirements(
  project_no, 
  hardware, 
  software
 )

Assignment(
  project_no, 
  employee_no
)
```

Here is what I want:

```
PROJECT_NO       EMPLOYEE_NO      HARDWARE       SOFTWARE  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
01                   1            MOUSE          SQL
01                   2            KEYBOARD          
01                   3                      
01                   4
```

Any ideas on how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Please do not use All_Caps letters. Change your question to use proper case. All_caps per internet etiquette means shouting. It is annoying.

Comment: You mean you want 2 tables from that single unnormalized table of yours??

Comment: Include the data in the underlying tables, and the query you are using to get the result you didn't want.

Comment: What you want is a very bad idea, you cannot tell who has what hardware or software. Your orginal query was correct. Perhaps you need to go back to school to learn how databases work.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are massively unclear from your question as you haven't included the data in your tables or the query you are using to get the result you didn't want.

However, I'm guessing this does what you want:

```
Select
  x.Project_No,
  x.Employee_No,
  y.Hardware,
  y.Software
From (
  Select
    a.*,
    RowNum As rn
  From
    Assignment a
  ) x Full Outer Join (
    Select
      r.*,
      RowNum As rn
    From
      Requirements r
  ) y on x.rn = y.rn
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88178/6

I feel I should point out this is a very stupid query as the values in columns 3 and 4 have nothing to do with the values in columns 1 and 2.

Comment: I agree 1,000,000% with your last statement

Comment: @HLGEM The only thing I can think is that the user wants to display a screen/page with a summary of a project on, containing the list of the people assigned, and resource required. Of course using two queries for this would be the sensible thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

Example using Oracle:

```
create table Requirements
(
  project_no integer not null
  ,hardware varchar2(64)
  ,software varchar2(64)
);

create table Assignment
(
  project_no integer not null
  ,employee_no integer not null
);

insert into Requirements (project_no, hardware, software)
values (1, 'Mouse', 'SQL'); 
insert into Requirements (project_no, hardware, software)
values ( 1, 'Keyboard', '');

insert into Assignment (project_no, employee_no)
values (1, 1);
insert into Assignment (project_no, employee_no)
values (1, 2);
insert into Assignment (project_no, employee_no)
values (1, 3);
insert into Assignment (project_no, employee_no)
values (1, 4);

select r.project_no, a.employee_no, r.hardware, r.software
from Assignment a
inner join Requirements r
on r.project_no = a.project_no;

select nvl(r.project_no, a.project_no) as project_no
, a.employee_no
, r.hardware
, r.software
from 
(
  select row_number() over (partition by project_no order by employee_no) r 
  , project_no
  , employee_no
  from Assignment
) a
full outer join 
(
  select row_number() over (partition by project_no order by hardware desc, software desc) r 
  , project_no
  , hardware
  , software
  from Requirements
) r
on r.project_no = a.project_no
and r.r = a.r;

drop table Assignment;
drop table Requirements;
```

Example using SQL Server (slight editing may be required for Oracle):

```
create table #Requirements
(
  project_no bigint not null
  ,hardware nvarchar(64)
  ,software nvarchar(64)
)

create table #Assignment
(
  project_no bigint not null
  ,employee_no bigint not null
)

insert #Requirements 
      select 1, 'Mouse', 'SQL'
union select 1, 'Keyboard', ''

insert #Assignment
      select 1, 1
union select 1, 2
union select 1, 3
union select 1, 4

--your original query
select r.project_no, a.employee_no, r.hardware, r.software
from #Assignment a
inner join #Requirements r
on r.project_no = a.project_no

--query which gives you the result you're after (though not recommended, since this isn't really how you should use SQL)
select isnull(r.project_no, a.project_no) project_no
, a.employee_no
, r.hardware
, r.software
from (select row_number() over (partition by project_no order by employee_no) r , * from #Assignment) a
full outer join (select row_number() over (partition by project_no order by hardware desc, software desc) r , * from #Requirements) r
on r.project_no = a.project_no
and r.r = a.r 

drop table #Assignment
drop table #Requirements
```

Comment: this looks like SQL Server syntax? OP's tagged the question as Oracle

Comment: Good point @Sathya - I've amended the answer to show that the example's based on T-SQL.  Sadly I don't have an Oracle DB at home to test queries against.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: you can use SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com There are several problems with that syntax regarding Oracle (select without from, insert without into, no `;` to terminate the statements)